# How to add a CSS Class to a QVBoxLayout

Tags: c++, css, qt, layout

A `QWidget` picks up CSS classes as expected:

```
leftContainerWrapper = new QVBoxLayout();
leftContainerWrapper -> setProperty("class", "top-bar-borders");
```

However, **QVBoxLayout** never do.

```
QVBoxLayout leftContainerWrapper = new QVBoxLayout();
leftContainerWrapper -> setProperty("class", "top-bar-borders");
```

How can I go about adding the style class, `top-bar-borders` below, to a **QHBoxlayout**?

```
.top-bar-borders {
    border-top: 2px solid  #5676C9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the layout inside an additional `QWidget` on which you set the property. For example:

```
QWidget * leftContainerWrapper = new QWidget();
leftContainerWrapper->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());
leftContainerWrapper->setProperty("class", "top-bar-borders");
```